# How to add custom button to Gmail

Tags: button, gmail

I would like to add my own button into Gmail left panel above the hangouts section,so that I can do some additional actions.

Is there any sample code to do this with out writing a browser plugin

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.